# Usage of diffuse vs. defuse

Tags: meaning, word-choice, synonyms, word-usage, homophones

I often hear phrases such as "infantry were sent in to diffuse/defuse the situation," and I am never *quite* sure which people are saying, and which is correct.  Both seem to make sense.

To me (a chemist/physicist) the primary definition of the *intransitive* verb "diffuse" has a very specific meaning: to move randomly through a medium.  I also understand the *transitive* verb "diffuse" to mean to make something less concentrated, or to lower its energy.

"Defuse," on the other hand, has one clear meaning: to remove the fuse from a bomb (or situation), making it less dangerous.

So the question is, when I hear "diffuse/defuse the situation," is there a more correct word to use, or is this a case where words are both homophones and synonyms?  (Which would be pretty cool.)

Comment: google for 'eggcorn'

Comment: There's a word for it!  That is what I was looking to describe.

Comment: In my sort of English they're also not quite homophones - the first syllable is longer in *defuse*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Defuse the situation** is the more sensible of the two:

It employs the metaphor that the situation is a bomb, and may explode.  Defusing it will render it harmless.

Diffusing a situation would mean to spread it out and make it less concentrated.  You can make a case that the intensity of the situation needs diffusion to make it less dangerous, but I believe it to be a stretching of the metaphor to the point where it seems to really be a mangling of *defuse*.

**Note, both are commonly used, so it's not *really* wrong to use diffuse.**

Comment: I think the vast majority of uses of *diffuse* are intended to be *defuse*.  Applied to an angry crowd for example either could apply - but the *crowd* would *diffuse*, *defusing* the *situation*.

Comment: But "sending in infantry to diffuse the situation" might unintentionally be more accurate than the normal metaphor "defuse the situation". The effect of the infantry might be to cause the situation to affect more people over a larger area for a longer period of time! Of course when that happens, typically the intensity is not reduced in proportion and so it is not a diffusion. And if the infantry has the intended effect of ending the conflict then again it's not diffusing the situation, it's reducing/eliminating it.

Comment: "both are commonly used, so it's not really wrong" No, _diffuse_ is clearly wrong in this usage. Just because a lot of people are illiterate and use the wrong word or phrase, doesn't make it right.

Comment: @Phil eventually common usage wins. And the meaning isn't *that* far off (per my comment above). If you said *swordfish* vs *defuse* that would be blatantly wrong.  See the comment above yours.

Answer (score 6):

'**Defuse** is a verb, which means 'to remove the fuse'. But it is often used figuratively, such as in 'UN forces were sent in to help defuse the tensions between the warring parties'.

'**Diffuse**, is also a verb, meaning to 'spread over a wide area, or among a larger number of people' such as 'the problem is how to diffuse power without creating anarchy'. But 'diffuse' is more frequently used as an adjective meaning 'widespread', or 'not concentrated'. 'Lacking clarity, the second proposal is more diffuse'.

Answer (score 5):

According to OED, the word [*defuse*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=defuse&searchmode=none) is coined in 1943, by combining *[de-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=de-&allowed_in_frame=0)* and [*fuse*(v.) (which is invented in 1680s as a back-formation from fusion, a noun came from Middle French *fusion*, from Latin *fusionem*)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fuse&allowed_in_frame=0), while the verb form of [*diffuse*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=diffuse&searchmode=none) is coined in 1520s from Latin *diffusus*, past participle of *diffundere* "to pour out or away".

Despite the similarities in spelling, they have different origins.

OOD suggests that [*defuse*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/defuse) can be defined as "to remove the fuse from (an explosive device) in order to prevent it from exploding" and "to make (a situation) less tense or dangerous", which is pretty different from the definition of [*diffuse*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/diffuse?q=diffuse).

> diffuse (v.)
>
> 1. Spread over a wide area or between a large number of people
> 2. Intermingle with another substance by movement, typically in a specified direction or at specified speed.
> 3. Cause (light) to spread evenly to reduce glare and harsh shadows.
>
> *Furthermore, diffuse can also be used as an adjective.*

So apparently, the expression *defuse the situation* makes more sense.

If you conduct a comparison in a Google Ngram, you will discover that this expression is also more widely used.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly,

- *diffuse* ends in an /**s**/
- *defuse* ends in a /**z**/

If you get that straight, there will be no problems.

Comment: That's only true of the adjective *diffuse*.  The verb *diffuse* ends with /z/.

Comment: Yes, but the verb is very rare in practice (like the verb _effect_ and the noun _affect_), and in context there's little problem, since _diffuse_ is intransitive, while _defuse_ is transitive.

Comment: @JohnLawler Examples that Oxford Dictionaries gives of *diffuse* as a verb are: 'The problem is how to *diffuse* power without creating anarchy' and 'Oxygen molecules *diffuse* across the membrane'. The first of those looks like a transitive use to me. So I am slightly puzzled at your mentioning it as intransitive.

Comment: I've never seen it used transitively as in the first example. It sounds odd to me, and from the fact that _power_ is used in construction with _anarchy_, I deduce that it's a political metaphor, so one may reasonably wonder at its distribution.